# Generate Random Coordinates in United States?

Tags: python, coordinates, geocoding, shapefile

I want to generate a random set of latitude and longitude coordinates in the US (including Hawaii and Alaska). I tried using a shapefile from the National Weather Service (https://www.weather.gov/gis/USstates ) but it was generating points in the middle of the ocean. What is the best way of doing this? I thought about defining my own polygon in the interior US but that would exclude some states. I’ve also seen other similar questions where they used a CSV list of US cities, but I’d rather it be completely random.

Comment: Are you able to make a function that, given a set of coordinates, detects whether or not they are inside the US?

Comment: Get the surface of Alaska, Hawaii and the rest. And so random (with weight) select one of them. Then with your method random latitude and longitude. Check if it is inside the shape (and outside lakes), if not do it again. If you want: just split per state (or group, so just skip gulf of Mexico, etc., so less tries). i think within few retry you get inside (but possibly Hawaii and Alaska

Comment: Have a look at the `Faker` library.
It seems it has interesting methods (and localized) to get random locations.
Faker [geoprovider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.geo.html?highlight=geo#faker.providers.geo.Provider).
Things like *"Returns a location known to exist on land in a country specified by country_code. Defaults to ‘en_US’."*

Answer (score 5):

This one requires `geopandas` but it's a quick and standard solution for sampling within odd shapes (called [Monte Carlo Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) ). Most of the comments below question outline the same concept.

## Solution

```
# grab shape within which to sample
url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_nation_20m.zip"
us = gpd.read_file(url).explode()
## filter out parts of the US that are far away from mainland, I have no idea what they are (Guam islands?)
us = us.loc[us.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.exterior.bounds[2])<-60]

# grab bounding box within which to generate random numbers
x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max = us.geometry.unary_union.bounds 

# the sampling
np.random.seed(2) # set seed (needed for reproducible results
N = 10000
rndn_sample = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(x_min,x_max,N),'y':np.random.uniform(y_min,y_max,N)}) # actual generation
# re-save results in a geodataframe
rndn_sample = gpd.GeoDataFrame(rndn_sample, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(x=rndn_sample.x, y=rndn_sample.y),crs = us.crs)

# filtering
inUS = rndn_sample['geometry'].apply(lambda s: s.within(us.geometry.unary_union)) # check if within the U.S. bounds
rndn_sample.loc[inUS,:].plot() # plot for visual inspection of results
```

## Explanation

### Grab US outline within which we want to randomly sample

```
# grab shapefile of the US from an official source
url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_nation_20m.zip"
us = gpd.read_file(url).explode()
```

Note, with `explode()`, I expand the multi-part polygon into separate rows. This enables for easier filtering of the area we are interested in because we can grab bounds for each part of the multi-part polygon as below. Note that `-60` is just an approximate longitude of the most eastern part of mainland US (Puerto Rico). Feel free to decrease it to exclude PR

```
## filter out parts of the US that are far away from mainland, I have no idea what they are (Guam islands?)
us = us.loc[us.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.exterior.bounds[2])<-60]
```

### Generate bounds for box within which to generate random coordinates

```
# grab bounding box within which to generate random numbers
x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max = us.geometry.unary_union.bounds # save min and max x/y coords
```

Note, `unary_union` is used to re-combine the individual rows into a single multi-part polygon and the `bounds` is used to grab the min/max of the x & y coordinates on the filtered subset of the U.S. (ie without guam islands)

### Sample within the box

```
np.random.seed(2) # set seed (needed for reproducible results
N = 10000
rndn_sample = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(x_min,x_max,N),'y':np.random.uniform(y_min,y_max,N)}) # actual generation
# re-save results in a geodataframe
rndn_sample = gpd.GeoDataFrame(rndn_sample, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(x=rndn_sample.x, y=rndn_sample.y),crs = us.crs)
```

### Check which random points are within US bounds

```
inUS = rndn_sample['geometry'].apply(lambda s: s.within(us.geometry.unary_union)) # check if within the U.S. bounds
rndn_sample.loc[inUS,:].plot() # plot for visual inspection of results
```

### Side note

Btw, here are the needed libraries in case it's ambiguous

```
# load libraries
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
```

## Notes On Sampling Efficiency

1. The smaller the box within which we are sampling, the more efficient is the sampler (only about 20% of sampled points land within U.S. territories in the current answer).
2. A more efficient solution would be to instead create a separate box for each of the areas (ie continental US, Hawaii, Alaska, etc), decide randomly from which one to sample (ie draw randomly either Hawaii, Alaska, or continental US based on, say, their land size relative to the total US size), then sample within that particular area. It's more work upfront but it could be significantly faster.